# The piano piece played near the end of episode 3 of K: Return of Kings

Tags: music, k-project

Does anyone know the song title in episode 3 of *K: Return of Kings*, starting at 21:04 when Neko calls out to Shiro for help?

Answer (score 1):

The song is entitled **K Return of Kings - Showdown**. You can listen to the music on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cu7qN-_80w0).

Answer (score 0):

It's track 22 in [K RETURN OF KINGS CHARACTER SONG & SOUNDTRACK CD](http://vgmdb.net/album/57125), titled *If you die..*. [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eMv7Qb-kQY) for YouTube listening.